# What is the standard c++ library?

Tags: c++

I've had this question on my C++ quiz.

> To use c++ standard library we write ...

1. `#include <iostream>`
2. `using namespace std;`
3. `import std;`
4. `None of the above`

I've answered it `#include <iostream>`. Because indeed `<iostream>` is a standard C++ library. When I asked the professor about the correct answer he said the correct answer is `using namespace std;`. Actually, the correct answer doesn't make sense to me. And also the question is confusing.

Comment: That is a pretty bad question. You can use the standard library, and most the time should, without including "using namespace std;" in your program. Also, you could include "using namespace std;" but then never actually use the standard library. Not sure what he is going for if what you have written is the full question.

Comment: The question is poorly formulated.  I would have chosen `#include <iostream>` or even "none of the above", as nowhere are using-directives mentioned in the [Using the library](https://eel.is/c++draft/using) section of the C++ standard.

Comment: Despite the 'using' keyword, you don't actually need to use 'using namespace std' to actually use std. Just prefix with the namespace and that's it. Including the headers is more logical, but... iostream is only part of the standard lib. Including that header is not enough to use everything from std. One really mandatory thing is to link it, and that's not included in the answers.

Comment: Related: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/9716597)

Comment: "To use c++ standard library we write ..." - to use it you need a C++ compiler and stdlib headers. `using namespace std` isn't a requirement on top of that - hell, as already linked, it's discouraged to use. Horribly phrased question, though - I recommend complaining about it to someone of significance at <insert your uni name here>, because #2 is everything but correct the way the question is worded

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` :-)

Comment: I guess it's true. Those who can't do... teach.

Comment: If it's any consolation, `1` is definitely the wrong answer.  The correct answer is `4`.  The professor's answer of `2` is also definitely the wrong answer.

Comment: @Eljay -- agreed, but the professor's answer reflects a common misconception, perhaps imported from other languages.

Comment: @Eljay Why 1 is definitely the wrong answer?

Comment: @user8721005 iostream is a part of the stdlib. Importing it is importing a part of the stdlib, but not the entire stdlib

Comment: In this test, you give zero mark to professor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the correct answer is `4`, "To use c++ standard library" doesn't really make any sense, you can use individual classes and functions from the standard library not the whole standard library.

1. This includes [one header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream) from the standard library allowing use of `std::cin` etc.
2. see [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), this just imports the `std` namespace into the global namespace and is not necessary to "use the c++ standard library"
3. When the standard library supports [c++ modules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules) this could be the correct answer